# How to detect device made in Worklight

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, device, user-agent

Is there a way to detect device made particularly Samsung or htc in Worklight or plain javascript?

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate of that question. What I need to know is Device made not Device OS. Thanks for Reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Cordova device.model. Doc: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device